# How to run "hadoop jar" as another user?

Tags: hadoop, jar

`hadoop jar` uses the name of the currently logged-in user. Is there a way to change this without adding a new system user?

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. What is this usage about and what it means using a user name without creating one?

Comment: You are right, please disregard it. Creating a user for the tasks is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is, through a feature called [Secure Impersonation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/Secure_Impersonation.html), which lets one user submit on behalf of another (that user must exist though). If you're running as the hadoop superuser, it's as simple as setting the env variable `$HADOOP_PROXY_USER`.

If you want to impersonate a user which doesn't exist, you'll have to do the above and then implement your own AuthenticationHandler.

If you don't have to impersonate too many users, I find it easiest to just create those users on the namenode and use secure impersonation in my scripts.